# Powershell: Unable to read data from the transport connection, when executed via Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script, which works fine, when I execute it via the powershell or via VS Code. But, when I try to execute it via the Task Scheduler (as Admin and with highes privileges ofc), then it doesn't work. I am using below PS code to search data in sharepoint. I assume this issue is with only those sharepoint libraray which have more than 100K data. Looks like Task schedular is not waiting for the result as below query takes around 5 minuts if Library have more than 100K data. Any help on how I can resolve it with Task schedular.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/Documnets"
$Docs = Get-PnPList | Where-Object { $_.BaseTemplate -eq 101 -and $_.Hidden -eq $false }
ForEach ($List in $Docs) { 
 Write-Host "Working on List Name :- " $List.Title
    $Items = Get-PnPListItem -List $List.Title -PageSize 5000 | Sort-Object ID -Descending | Where-Object { ("1213356" -eq $_.FieldValues."AppNumber") } 
   
     Write-Host "Item found to update: $($Items.count)"
    If ($Items.Count -gt 0) {  
        WriteLog -level INFO -message "Record found"           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue, here are some things to check:

- Make sure that the "Start In (optional)" field in the Task Scheduler action tab is set to the directory of your script.
- Check the settings in the Actions tab. The Program/script field should be set to `Powershell` and the Add arguments field should be set to `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "your-script.ps1"`
- Include Out-File cmdlets in your script to write to a log file for troubleshooting. You could also use `Start-Transcript`/`Stop-Transcript` for more detailed logging.
- Verify that the user account running the task has the necessary permissions. The account might need to be allowed to 'Logon as a batch job'.

Comment: I followed the above steps, but unfortunately, I am still facing the error below. I noticed that my script taking 15 minutes to return the result from SharePoint when I run it from command prompt. But Task scheduler is throwing an error just after 10 minutes. I used Start-Transcript and got this error - TerminatingError(Get-PnPListItem): "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.."

Comment: On the Settings tab, there is an option to “stop the task if it runs longer than”. You might have that enabled and set to 10 minutes. If not then the connection to SharePoint may not be authenticating correctly. You may need to setup a connection through app registration. Consider adding error handling in your script to catch and log exceptions. This can provide more detailed information about where and why the script is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Above suggestion was very helpfull. I just tuned my script to search in sharepoint that have fixed transport connection error. Below is the tuned script

```
Get-PnPListItem -List $List.Title -PageSize 1000  -ScriptBlock { Param($_s) $_s.Context.ExecuteQuery() } | Where-Object {$_["FileLeafRef"] -like "*.*"} | ForEach-Object {
            if("1213356" -eq $_.FieldValues.$AppField){
                $ListItems += $_
  }       
 }
```